# What the suitable Regular expression pattern for `<span><li> .... </li></span>`?

Tags: c#, regex

I wrote the following regular expression for the texts below:

```
"\<li\>\<span\>[\w\d\s\-\,\/\;]+\<\/span\>\<\/li\>"
```

HTML:

```
"<li><span>3-1/2-inch cutting edge and wedge-shaped spike</span></li>"
"<li><span>19-inch overall length; 24-ounce weight</span></li>"
```

But it doesn't work! What is the suitable pattern for that?

Comment: `.*` — Really, just use an HTML parser to do it. A regex is not the right tool for parsing HTML.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.*?` to match everything until something else (lazy matching):

```
"<li><span>.*?<\/span><\/li>"
```

You can test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/kU5tW9/1).